# Downloading a file from the custom API in python

Tags: android, python-3.x, rest, flask-restful, pytube

The code mentioned below is a custom API using python basically what it does is it gets a link from the user and parses it to a function and download the particular video from youtube the parse is working but I need to fetch the download which is coming from it I'm new to restful API please go through the code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify
from pytube import YouTube

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

     def youtube_api(self,link):
         yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+link)
         stream = yt.streams.filter(res='720p')
         stream.first().download()  

class Test(Resource):
    def get(self,link):
        api_link = str(link)
        youtube_api(link)
        return jsonify(api_link)

api.add_resource(Test,'/api/<link>')        


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port='5002')
```

The class Test takes in the link through a GET method and passes the link to the youtube_api function the code `stream.first().download()`downloads the file and stores it. The youtube_api function was a standalone script so I'm trying to integrate this with my custom api the api will be used in Mobile Apps so how can return the back to Json

There is no error while running the server:
[image: Server Log]

Comment: What's not working? Include full text of any errors you are getting. You are wanting to return the result of this script into a JSON response? What in your script does not do that?

Comment: I'm not getting any error the link is getting passed to the youtube_api but no download is happening in the background see the youtube_api function

Comment: Looking at the api (https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/63c395447f06045bc27f0dce28550a81dbdda6de/tests/test_streams.py#L35), maybe the call should be in two steps for `stream`. In function `def youtube_api(self,link):` have you tried `stream = yt.streams.filter(res='720p').first();`, then 
`stream.download()`

Comment: Yup both are same but this runs in a server how it can be downloaded and the pytube runs as a standalone script in api you have listed

Comment: I got that fixed you were right the file was being downloaded in the background and was stored in the place where script was running but how can i redirect the download to a browser or to an application which is requesting it

Comment: That depends on the server framework you are using to host your content.